# Read a Javascript cookie-value from a .NET codebehind

Tags: javascript, .net, cookies

In my  part of the web page I have put a value in a Javascript cookie like this:

```
function SkrivJSCookie() {
         document.cookie = "test_cookie=Test99";
         }
```

In my codebehind (VB), I want to have the value of the cookie ('Test99') transferred to a textbox (Textbox1) when a button is clicked.

From a large Google search it seems, that the solution may be to use 'HttpServletRequest' in some way, but I cannot make it work at all.

It seems like a pretty simple issue but how can this be accomplished?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just read it from the request like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(CookieName)`. Depending on your framework and language.

Comment: `but I cannot make it work at all` perhaps you did it wrong, we'll never ever know if you never ever show

Comment: setting document.cookie then clicking a button has nuff all to do with the server, so how do you expect the server to even know what you did on the browser? Does the button click cause a postback (or whatever arcane lingo microsoft uses)

Comment: Based on comment from Lain, I found that this code works:

Dim x As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("test_cookie")
Dim y As String = x.Value
TextBox2.Text = y

Comment: I am not too trained in this forum - I cannot isolate the code section. Sorry!